# Python Dict Key search and counter value in large file

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, defaultdict

I am looking for an efficient way to scan a huge log file for particular strings and do a counter for each string found.  I am hoping to write the method so that it’ll be easily expandable in future, I have looked into defaultdict(int), but I am only finding examples to count **all** words in a string.

To make things even more difficult I am looking to go down the dict Key:[List] approach where Key would be the one of the search strings and the list so I can add a few credentials to each of the keys so that I can reference them later in the script, and so that it is easily expandable without having to make changes dotted around the script.

Something like...

```
mycounterdict = {'Mondeo':['Total Fords', 0, 'Belgium'], 'Passat':['Total VWs',0, 'Germany'], 'A4':['Total Audis', 0, 'Germany']}
```

The application I use to read the logs is structured to pass a full 'data group' to the script (in this case 'CARinfo', although these are intermingled with other 'data groups').

visual example of a typical log (NB: dotted line outlines the block of text passed to the script each time 'CARinfo' is found).

```
Group ID: CARinfo, for Year 20xx
Car model = Mondeo
Year Purchased, 2014

Group ID: FUELinfo, for Year 20xx
Type: Diesel

Group ID: CARinfo, for Year 20xx
Car model = Passat
Year Purchased, 2012
--------------------------------    
Group ID: CARinfo, for Year 20xx
Car model = Passat
Year Purchased, 2011
--------------------------------
```

My script would then search through a large data log first to match a 'CARinfo' data group and then look for a Key match anywhere in the data group.  If I find a Key match (e.g. Mondeo) then I want to increment the dict value[1] (list entry [1])

I was looking at doing something like this, but I'm wondering if I need a complete re-think on the method, which started off simple, but now looks too intricate!

```
path = C:\apath
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:  
        if filename.endswith('.log'): 
            filenameext = filename.split(".log")
            f = root+'\\'+filename
            print "\tCurrently working on file: "+filename

            logtool.open_log(f)
            mygroup = logtool.app.DataGroup

            while (mygroup.Next()):
                if 'CARinfo' in mygroup.Text:
                    for k, v in mycounterdict:
                        if k in mypkt.Text:
                            v[1]+=1

            print mycounterdict
```

Thanks,
MikG

Comment: Believe me...this is no where near "intricate" :) Just keep going you're defiantly on the right path. You might also want to look into ``collections.Counter`` for counting the occurrence of a string/obj. Basically after your finished producing ``mycounterdict``, throw it in a Counter class and simply query it. Ex: do something like : ``print(Counter(mycounterdict))``

Comment: Thanks @notorious, I got a bit further with your suggestions